# Apply Function with multiple parameter

Tags: r, apply

Here is the data source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5jsvwbzz5fumqp/countyComplete.csv?dl=0

I want to multiply 2 columns (pop2010 * percapitaincome) for each county and then divide it by the count of state, grouped by state.

How can I do it using any of the apply functions in R.

here my try

```
myfun<-function(x,y){
  x*y
  }

y<-county$per_capita_income

t<-tapply(county$pop2010,county$state,myfun,y=y)
```

Comment: You could use either one of aggregating functions, or dplyr, data.table.  Did you try anything.  Also, there is no column named `county` in your dataset.

Comment: Tell what u have done to do this? where are u struck ? and provide small reproducible example.

Comment: @akrun name is the county column

Comment: Based on the description, I guess you need to first group by `name` (or county) and get the new column which is the product of the two variables. then get the count of state (may be `length`) grouped by `state` and then divide the new column by that that count. In dplyr, you may try `df1 %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(newCol= pop2010 * percapitaincome) %>% group_by(state) %>% mutate(newCol=newCol/n())`

Comment: Or this: `with(county, tapply(pop2010/10000*per_capita_income, state, function(x) x/length(x)))` (had to rescale `pop2010` due to integer overflow.)

Comment: This is a case where's there no need or performance reason to `groupby`. A simple `tapply` should vectorize much more nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rescaled pop2010 in order to avoid integer overflow.**

```
with(county, tapply((pop2010/10000)*per_capita_income, state, function(x) x/length(x)))
```

*answer posted by jbaums*